# Convert an array to it to the single array and also assign key to the object values

Tags: angular

I have nested Object Format in which there is no key  assigned to the values, the format is shown below:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "2019": {
      "January": {
        "complaintRaised": 9,
        "totalPending": 4,
        "totalClosed": 0,
        "resolvedPercent": 0
      }
    },
    "2018": {
      "May": {
        "complaintRaised": 9,
        "totalPending": 4,
        "totalClosed": 0,
        "resolvedPercent": 0
      }
    }

  },

}
```

which I need to convert it into a single array with key

```js
response.data: [{
    key: "2019"
    "complaintRaised": 9,
    "totalPending": 4,
    "totalClosed": 0,
    "resolvedPercent": 0
    year: "2019-January"
  },
  {
    key: "2018"
    "complaintRaised": 9,
    "totalPending": 4,
    "totalClosed": 0,
    "resolvedPercent": 0
    year: "2018-May"
  }
]
```

assign to the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will solve this problem

```
function render({data}) {
const entries :any[] = Object['entries'](data);

const result = entries.map(yearData => {
  let key = yearData[0];
  let month = Object.keys(yearData[1])[0];
  let monthData = yearData[1][month];

  return {
    key,
    ...monthData,
    year : `${key}-${month}`
  }

})
return result;
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-stackoverflow-54307904)

***Updated :***

in case we have many months

```
function render({ data }) {
  const entries: any[] = Object['entries'](data);
  return entries.map(([key, data]) =>
    Object.keys(data).map(month => ({
      key,
      ...data[month],
      year: `${key}-${month}`
    }))
  ).reduce((acc: any[], next: any[]) => acc.concat(next), [])
}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-stackoverflow-54307904-2)

Comment: This will not work in case when there are more than one month for the same year

Comment: @Andriy I have updated my answer also yours look very well too 

Answer (score 1):

The first answer will not work in case there are more than one month for the same year like in the following example. This code will process all the months.

```js
const dataInput = {
  "data": {
    "2019": {
      "January": {
        "complaintRaised": 9,
        "totalPending": 4,
        "totalClosed": 0,
        "resolvedPercent": 0
      },
      "March": {
        "complaintRaised": 91,
        "totalPending": 41,
        "totalClosed": 10,
        "resolvedPercent": 10
      }
    },
    "2018": {
      "May": {
        "complaintRaised": 9,
        "totalPending": 4,
        "totalClosed": 0,
        "resolvedPercent": 0
      }
    }
  }
}

const response = {
  data: Object.entries(dataInput.data).reduce((res, [year, val]) => ([
    ...res, 
    ...Object.entries(val).reduce((res2, [month, val2]) => ([
      ...res2,
      {
        key: year,
        ...val2,
        year: `${year}-${month}`
      }
    ]), []),
  ]), [])
};

console.log(response);
```